# Pyro4: how to cast a list of tuples with Pyrolite in Java?

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, pyro

After installing [Pyro4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pyro4/4.41) and adding [pyrolite](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/razorvine/pyrolite/4.10/pyrolite-4.10.jar) and [serpent](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/razorvine/serpent/1.12/serpent-1.12.jar) jars to Java build path, using codes similar to the [client and server side python codes](https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/intro.html) which work OK with the Python client codes, I use some codes similar to the Java example on https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/pyrolite.html to access a Python server object.

```
import net.razorvine.pyro.*;

NameServerProxy ns = NameServerProxy.locateNS("127.0.0.1");
PyroProxy remoteobject = new PyroProxy(ns.lookup("example.greeting"));
List<String> inputWords = getExampleWords();
Object result = remoteobject.call("predictedResults", inputWords );
System.out.println("result = "+result );
remoteobject.close();
ns.close();
```

The printed python clent side result is similar to:

```
>> print 'result = \n' + str(result)

result =
[(u'aaa', 0.88877496454662064), (u'bbb', 0.019192749769012061), (u'?', 0.0070963814247323219), (u'ccc', 0.0068011253515576015), (u'home', 0.00148328236618)]
```

The data structure is a list of tuples, each of which a pair of string and float, like:

```
result = []
for i in xrange(10):
    result.append((list[i], value[i]))
```

And the Java result printed on console is:

```
>> Object result = remoteobject.call("predictedResults", inputWords );
>> System.out.println("result = "+result );

result = [[Ljava.lang.Object;@2e0fa5d3, [Ljava.lang.Object;@5010be6, [Ljava.lang.Object;@685f4c2e, [Ljava.lang.Object;@7daf6ecc, [Ljava.lang.Object;@2e5d6d97]
```

The question is: how to succesfully cast 'Object result = remoteobject.call("predictedResults", inputWords );' to a list of pairs of string and float in Java?

Comment: This is really a Java question, not a Python one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error I finally found the answer:

```
Object result = remoteobject.call("predictedResults", inputWords );
System.out.println("result = " + result);

ArrayList<Object[]> resultList = (ArrayList<Object[]>) result;
for (Object element : resultList) {
    Object[] pair = (Object[]) element;
    System.out.println((String)pair[0] + ", " + (Double)pair[1]); 
}
```